# Machine learning in cab pooling scenario?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

So I have this dataset for a transportation problem. Which shows a cab pooling scenario. Consider the following image:

[image]

The users with same ride number went in the same cab (each user has the same starting point so please ignore that). Now that means, Y, Z and A are in same proximity, and so as B & C and D & E.

Now I would like to fit this dataset into a machine learning model such that when I enter the destination of any user, the model should give me the prediction on with whom my destination can be coupled so I can go in the cab with those people.

Like if I have to go to a location 'C' I can join people who are going to 'B'.

Which machine learning algorithm can I use in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do without machine learning algorithm. Given the ride number, you can identify locations which are close to each other and group them. When a new location comes, you can see which group it belongs to and pair the people traveling to locations within that group.

To do this you can create a matrix which has locations `A, B,C,...` as the rows and as columns. What you'll get is a `num_of_locations x num_of_locations` matrix. For the cell with row label `B` and column label `C` you can mark it as 1 since they are in proximity and the locations which aren't in proximity(like `A` and `B`) should be marked as zero.

The matrix will be a symmetric one, so if you have too many locations you can save on memory and computation by some optimizations. You can research around saving triangular matrices as sparse matrices.

Also, if you have access to the right resources(paid libraries), you can replace the 0,1 with distances(displacements actually).

Comment: Yes, that process is pretty straightforward, rather, we can also use google map's direction API, but for the matter of fact,  we've to create a cognitive solution here and therefore we need some machine learning algorithm.